# Selector drawables

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-selector

I have the following definition of an android style and selector applied to `ListView`, however I see no effect of gray gradient applied when I click on it. On click it immediately displays blue gradient.

As author of this example has written:

> We want to apply this to our list selector. Instead of always showing
>   the same gradient, we want the gradient to change its start color from
>   grey to a light blue whenever a list item is pressed. Because we now
>   have two different list selectors—one for default state one for
>   pressed state—we need to keep them in separate files.

Can someone explain how it should be displayed properly ? Or I'm missing something ?
**More general, what exactly I should expect to see on display screen ? Something like fluent transition from gray gradient to blue gradient on list item click ?**

**Update:** this is how author 'sees' it, but when I click on item it looks only like on right side of picture. May I assume that author wants to see all items in list to be gray by default ? Or this state is not applicable to list view items ?
[image]

> **list_item_default.xml  -> GRAY GRADIENT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#FFFF"
        android:startColor="#AFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#CCC" />
    <corners android:radius="5px" />
</shape>
```

> **list_item_pressed.xml -> BLUE GRADIENT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#FFFF"
        android:startColor="#AA66CCFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#CCC" />
    <corners android:radius="5px" />
</shape>
```

> **list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_default" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

> **styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyMoviesTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyMoviesListView</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/film_bg</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyMoviesTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <!--<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>-->
  </style>

  <style name="MyMoviesListView" parent="@android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/list_background</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:footerDividersEnabled">false</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a sentence：

```
    <item 
    android:state_enabled="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_default"/>
    <item
    android:state_enabled="true"  
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed" 
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I'm not exactly sure what I should see on display screen when I press list item. Currently all items are by default black, when I click on one of them it becomes blue gradient. What I should expect to see ?

Comment: I try it and 4.11 can work well.I get gradient effect.Now I test it at 2.3.7,4.0.Your code can work well.

Comment: Well for me, I don't see the gray effect :P, I'm not sure I properly understand selectors then, when I should see gray gradient and when blue ? When I press element on list it turns blue, so when it should be gray ? By default none of elements on list is selected and all are dark like on image I gave.

Comment: I got what you want to do.By default none of elements on list ,<item name="android:background">@color/list_background</item>,you will see the color of list_background.If you want to see your picture,your code can't work.You mean by default none of elements on list the color was dark,but do you know which item should be the gray ?No!You don't know,so you may be do it like this.If the item was checked,it will be set backgroud with the gray.Otherwise it will be dark.If it was clicked,the selector wolud take effect.I hope you can understand my English.....